# I am not able to figure out why these two pieces of code work differently

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This piece of code works fine and increments the count every second.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function IntervalHookCounter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const tick = () => {
      console.log("Called tick")
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount+1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(tick, 1000)
      return () => {
          clearInterval(interval)
      }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IntervalHookCounter
```

But this piece of code only goes up 1 count and then stops

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function IntervalHookCounter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const tick = () => {
      console.log("Called tick")
      setCount(count+1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(tick, 1000)
      return () => {
          clearInterval(interval)
      }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IntervalHookCounter
```

Any idea why this might be the case.
Please help this is getting really confusing.

Comment: They are exactly same code, line by line, have you made an error while pasting the code here?

Comment: Yes I made a mistake fixed it now though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 3):

***The first code block***  - is using the `previous state` to increment the `count`, i.e. Take the previous value and increment by 1. ***Prev state is updated in the callback***

***In your second code block***, -  `setCount(count+1)` doesn't have access to the new `count` value in the subsequent render because the `useEffect()` is not invoked the second time. `count` always has the value of `0` within the setInterval callback, (`0` is the `default` state)

Answer (score 1):

This line screws you over:
`setCount(count+1)`

cause `count` is constant from outer scope and it is always `0` (even if it was `let` you never reassign it) so effectively you end up always with `0+1` in 2nd example

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

this has to do with closures.

- In short the first tick make sure that we add 1 to the previous state each second.
- the Second add 1 to count and for the function tick the count is always 0 (the first value of the count) so the function is fired every second but `count + 1` is always `1` because count is always `0` for the tick function